# What happens if a part uses more current than the regulator is rated for?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I want to use a 5 volt regulator to regulate a circuit's voltage and the regulator is rated for 1.5 amps.

If my circuit would use more than 1.5 amps, would the regulator just not supply it or would it blow up? I know that if you have a power supply that can provide less current than the circuit uses it will just not supply it, but here the regulator has access to more than the rated current.

I can't for my life find any explanation for this, maybe it's just me that doesn't know what to search for but either way can someone explain this?

Comment: I can't quite make sense of this. You need to provide a schematic of your circuit. What is the transistor doing? Because you mention a 5V regulator, then say the transistor? Is the transistor part of the regulator circuit? Please edit your question and **draw a schematic** to make it a bit clearer

Comment: You should include a **schematic**. *the transistor is rated for 1.5 amps* What transistor? That 1.5 A means that the manufacturer guarantees that the transistor can handle at least 1.5 A assuming all other ratings are met as well. I mean, I can **destroy** a 1.5 A transistor with **only 0.1 A** by using a high voltage so that the **power rating** is exceeded. Transistors are **not** self protecting, it is **your** responsibility not to exceed 1.5 A (and not to exceed the power rating).

Comment: ```5 volt regulator ... transistor is rated for 1.5 amps ...``` I think OP means some TO220 variant of a 7805, calling it a transistor because transistors come in TO220 housing too...

Comment: @Huisman That is possible, but we cannot know until OP is able to clarify. They could also be referring to some kind of pass transistor too. or possibly one used in a different part of the circuit. It is likely OP is referring to the regulator as a transistor, but I don't think it can be answered definitively until we know for sure

Comment: It's like if you'd be rated to cary 100kg on your back but someone loads you with 150kg. You probably won't colapse instantly and make some meters but you'll surrender sooner or later.
So if you have enough cooling power you may can even "overload" the transistor a bit, also depends whether we're talking about continuous load or just some peaks but it would be better to just find one that's rated for your current.

Comment: Im so sorry that i called it an transistor i meant an regulator.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up voltage regulators and transistors.

There are voltage regulators (like the common [7805](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l78.pdf)) that are packaged in the [TO-220 housing.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TO-220)

The TO-220 looks like this:

[image]

That housing is also commonly used for transistors, so it is easy to mix them up when looking at just the housing.

A transistor and a voltage regulator a vastly different things, though.

[Here's the circuit diagram of a transistor (only what is inside the housing:)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#NPN)

[image]

Here's the internal circuit of the 7805 regulator (borrowed from the datasheet linked above:)

[image]

As you can see, the regulator is composed of many transistors - and other parts as well.

So, it is not appropriate to speak of a regulator as "a transistor."

Now, to your question.

What happens if you try to draw more than the rated current depends on the regulator.

From the datasheet:

> The L78 Series of fixed voltage regulators are designed with thermal overload protection that shuts down the circuit when subjected to an excessive power overload condition, internal short-circuit protection that limits the maximum current the circuit will pass, and output transistor safe-area compensation that reduces the output shortcircuit current as the voltage across the pass transistor is increased.

It has three mechanisms to handle over loads:

1. Thermal shutdown.  It turns off if it gets too hot.  Mostly applies if you draw current with in the allowed limits, but without an adequate heat sink.  Dropping 12V to 5V at 1.5A requires getting rid of 10 watts of power - that requires a fair sized chunk of metal as a heat sink.
2. Internal short circuit protection - it will shutdown if you apply a deadshort to its output, or try to draw more than the rated current.  If your circuit wants more than 1.5A, it won't get it.
3. Safe operating operating area for the output transistor - the maximum current can be reduced if the voltage difference between input and output is too large.

To summarize:  You have to try **really** hard to kill a 7805 regulator.

Other regulators may have more protection built in, or less.  The 78XX series was intended to be a workhorse - it isn't the best performance wise, but will take a lot of abuse and keep right on working.

In any case, check the datasheet of what ever regulator you use.  It will tell you what it can handle and what you need to plan for.

---

You'll see that bit of advice ("check the datasheet") repeated often.  It is really your first step in using pretty much any electronic component.

---

In case you really meant "transistor," things are much simpler.  If you short it to ground such that more than the rated current flows through it, then it will burn out.

Depending on how much too much current you pass through it, it may silently stop work, burn out and release smoke, or explode a spray shattered bits of plastic around the room.

Comment: For what it's worth, those protections don't always work or even every time. I've had plenty of thermally protected parts blow up on me, including regulators.

Comment: Covered the transistor case as well.